# Should requests on site Metas be closed when completed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, per-site-meta

Here's a simple, appropriate request that was submitted on Meta.Law.SE: [Add tag for "tax" for tax law questions](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/10)

When such a request is completed is there a reason *not* to close the "question?"

(Reason to close in an example like this: It's a request that is no longer applicable.  It is not a question (in the SE sense); it cannot accumulate helpful or good answers.  It has become noise: for example, if I am looking for good, unanswered, or just open questions to address I wouldn't want stuff like that in the list.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing a question is essentially a nomination for deleting it (unless improvements are made). Are you planning to delete that post? If not, do not close it.

One does not need a reason to not close something; one needs a reason to close. Generally, "closed" does not mean "answered", it's more like "should not have been posted".

The moderator-only tags [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), etc, are more appropriate than closing an on-topic meta post. Posts with such tags can be filtered out by `-[status*]` search parameter.

Comment: Just amended question with reasons to close.

Comment: Marking meta posts as resolved is what [status-*] tags are for.

Comment: Ah, of course.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It is the history of the site; why remove that?

It's useful to have the history public so you can always refer the people who disagree in the future back to why a decision was taken originally. There will be people who disagree no matter how trivial the decision seems now. There'll also be genuinely curious people. Don't be mean to them.

There's a certain amount of revisionism that goes on naturally in humanity when an event moves further into the dusky past. [ahem](http://www.theguardian.com/media/2015/feb/11/brian-williams-nbc-suspends-news-anchor-for-six-months-over-helicopter-story). If that event is properly documented and available to all it's considerably easier to help/refute anyone who misremembers the past.

Comment: I was just thinking of sort of "tucking it out of the way" or "archiving" it.  After all: Nothing online is every _really_ deleted for those who care to look!  (Though part of the reason for asking is I'm not certain of the mechanics here.)